# reading selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript

i am trying to read selected value from dropdown list( `ddDocTypes`) . So in the IE I am able to get value using `Form1.ddDocTypes.options(Form1.ddDocTypes.selectedIndex).innerText`. But the same code give me "Form1.ddDocTypes.options undefined" error in Chrome.

Any suggestions !!

Comment: Here's the first suggestion, create a snippet demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yes,, looks like it

Comment: i tried all the opetion mention in mention post

Comment: As mentioned before, add your HTML and JS, so we can better help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are just trying to get the value of the selected from the dropdown, but this is how you do it in plain javascript (guessing from your tag)

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddDocTypes");
var inner = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: I already tried it still give me same error.

Comment: Then you really need to add an example in a fiddle like https://jsfiddle.net/